# Why the auto reboot not working?

Tags: 14.04, cron, reboot

Why the system is not rebooting? i have this following in the crontab under root username.

```
uptime: 08:43:06 up 10 days, 13:28,  2 users,  load average: 0,17, 0,08, 0,06
```

but it should be rebooting daily which is not happening:

```
5 7 * * * reboot
50 13 * * * reboot
5 19 * * * reboot
5 21 * * * reboot

5 0 * * * reboot
5 1 * * * reboot
5 2 * * * reboot
5 3 * * * reboot
5 4 * * * reboot
5 5 * * * reboot
5 6 * * * reboot
```

Comment: Are you editing the root's crontab ?  `crontab -e` ?

Comment: YES - roots crontab -e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use full path, for example:

```
/sbin/reboot
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/6a0JtnU.png - i have applied as you said. But how can i tomorrow verify that all the reboot worked ? (10 days ago i also applied but i was not sure if it ever worked, how do i know if it worked to check tomorrow?)